# Запускаю код, ввожу одну строку, код создает еще одну(пустую) строку, итого: 2 строки, а надо 1 строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
processed_text = ""

text_line = input()

while len(text_line) > 0:
    processed_text += text_line + '\n'

    text_line = input()

print(processed_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

@user466027, Программа работает так как написали: ввод, суммирование строк с переносом строки, пустой ввод для выхода из цикла, вывод суммы строк.. Что конкретно Вас не устраивает?

Знак '\n' - это перенос каретки. Соответственно у Вас всегда будет 2 строки

Comment: Сайт не считает 2 строки, нужна одна

Comment: @user466027, либо убирайте "\n", либо если Вам нужен список строк, то сделайте processed_text.split("\n") - он вернет Вам список строк по одной